Aws Auth flow not enabled for this client
I initialized aws backend project by running amplify init to connect to aws console (pass access and secret key and successfully connected to it)for a react native project.There were already pre-made function, Api (Graphql) and auth in the project under the amplify directory. I pushed them to aws console. But when I execute the functions I keep getting:
Auth Flow Error
I also tried using the query in App Sync but the error was still the same, I kept getting: Auth Flow not enabled for this client.
I ran the amplify function update command and added the following environment variables:

COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID: Set from the Cognito user pool ID.

COGNITO_CLIENT_ID: Taken from the app integration of the user pool, using the client ID ending with "web_client". I also tried creating a new client ID, but the same error persists.

ADMIN_USER_USERNAME: Provided the admin username.

ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD: Provided a secure password.


Additionally, I enabled the following authentication flows for all client IDs:
ALLOW_USER_SRP_AUTH, ALLOW_CUSTOM_AUTH, ALLOW_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH
After making these changes, I pushed the function. But still the error is there. Thanks for the help!
The Primary authorization mode for the AppSync is Amazon Cognito User Pool. The User pool id is the value of COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID that I put in the function environment variable.
If it helps my aws-export.js generated was:
const awsmobile = {
    "aws_project_region": "<YOUR_AWS_PROJECT_REGION>",
    "aws_cognito_identity_pool_id": "<YOUR_AWS_COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL_ID>",
    "aws_cognito_region": "<YOUR_AWS_COGNITO_REGION>",
    "aws_user_pools_id": "<YOUR_AWS_USER_POOLS_ID>",
    "aws_user_pools_web_client_id": "<YOUR_AWS_USER_POOLS_WEB_CLIENT_ID>",
    "oauth": {},
    "aws_cognito_username_attributes": [
        "EMAIL",
        "PHONE_NUMBER"
    ],
    "aws_cognito_social_providers": [],
    "aws_cognito_signup_attributes": [
        "EMAIL"
    ],
    "aws_cognito_mfa_configuration": "OFF",
    "aws_cognito_mfa_types": [
        "SMS"
    ],
    "aws_cognito_password_protection_settings": {
        "passwordPolicyMinLength": 8,
        "passwordPolicyCharacters": []
    },
    "aws_cognito_verification_mechanisms": [
        "EMAIL"
    ],
    "aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint": "<YOUR_AWS_APPSYNC_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT>",
    "aws_appsync_region": "<YOUR_AWS_APPSYNC_REGION>",
    "aws_appsync_authenticationType": "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS",
    "aws_user_files_s3_bucket": "<YOUR_AWS_USER_FILES_S3_BUCKET>",
    "aws_user_files_s3_bucket_region": "<YOUR_AWS_USER_FILES_S3_BUCKET_REGION>"
};

